# How to print white/light pixels as light-grey/white rather than underlying paper color

Tags: transparency, digital-printing, paper

[image]

This file was created in photoshop & illustrator, and I'll be printing it digitally on a color laser copier at Kinkos. As you can see, there are a lot of very light tones and that when printed, a good portion of the underlying paper will show through. And if I were printing on white paper, it would be fine. However, I want to print on manilla or ivory colored paper, but still keep the light tones as white (or very light greys) rather than them appearing to be manilla/ivory like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that without white ink (on a press) this cannot be done, but I'd love to be proven wrong. Any ideas/suggestions for getting close are welcomed.

Thanks!!

Comment: Normal CMYK printing has no white ink component. So, yes you are correct. You would need some white ink/toner.  Can't see how this would be possible otherwise. There are some digital printers which can print opaque white using a 5th white toner in addition to CMYK. One example is the Ricoh Pro C7100X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably **won't** be proven wrong.

Without the use of *actual white ink* (and a press, not a copier), there's nothing you can do to make white miraculously appear on a non-white stock.

The highest/brightest value possible is ***always*** that of the stock, unless a "lighter-than-the-stock" ink is used. It's not such a big hurdle for a commercial press. But it's impossible for a digital copier, unless the copier supports spot colors.

Some models of the Fiery copiers often employed at places like Kinko's *can* support spot colors: [SEE HERE](https://digitalprinting.blogs.xerox.com/2010/09/10/spot-colors-and-fiery-everything-you-need-to-know/) Whether your local Kinko's has one of these models is another matter.

The general practice for a press is that a base ink of the light color is laid down then other inks are overprinted on top of it. I don't know how that would work for a copier. But with spot color support you *might* be able to configure something which adds at least some highlights, even if something like a base ink isn't possible.

Comment: thanks for confirming